# I am new in Recyclerview.i want to show recyclerview for every bottomnavigationview item.how can i do it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

this is my first question in stackoverflow.if you dont understant anything i am sorry for that :should i use fragment instead Framelayout??

Here's my xml of bottomnavigation

````
            ```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/bottomnavid"
                >

            </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomnavid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
                /> 
  ```
````

here's  my xml of recyclerview xml :
           ```

````
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featurerecyclerid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```
````

Here is my  myadapter class:

````
```
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cardview,viewGroup,false);
                Myviewholder VH = new Myviewholder(v);
                return VH;
            }
        //replacing the contents of a view 
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myviewholder myviewholder, int i) {
                myviewholder.nametext.setText(Citynames.get(i));


            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return Citynames.size();
            }
        }
````

the project builds withot any error but its not showing the recyclerview  how can i implement recyclerview in this part,i think the problem is here..help me out please

````
        public class Feature extends Fragment {
            ArrayList<String> Citynames = new ArrayList<>    (Arrays.asList("dhaka","rongpur","bagura","sylhet","vhola"));
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                final View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feature,container,false);
                final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
                final RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.featurerecyclerid);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(c);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                 Myadapter myadapter = new Myadapter(Citynames,c);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feature,container,false);
            }
        }


 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what really you are trying to do,what appears to me you wronged with the layout,before trying recycler view first practice some different types of layout which will help to understand you how design object works in xmal attribute,try your layout like this

```
  <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/bottomnavid"
                >
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featurerecyclerid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomnavid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
                />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Did you create any inner class for initializing your `R.layout.cardview` ?Another thing is you have to initialize and set your `RecyclerView` with `Adapter` in `onViewCreated()` method in your Fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
                final RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.featurerecyclerid);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(c);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                 Myadapter myadapter = new Myadapter(Citynames,c);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
  }
```

Comment: i want to show a recyclerview on  a framelayout.i an activity there will be a bottomnavigationview t the bottom,above that there is a framelayout where i want to put a recyclerview.

Comment: every thing is done(adapter,viewholder,cardview) but recyclerview is not showing

Comment: Edit your question.Firstly post all your layout include adapter layout and adapter class.I mean not partially posted code,you make some ovious error which I meantion in my answer.also fixed this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597292/how-to-implement-recyclerview-on-a-freamelayout
hope you will understand this one

Comment: set your recycler view and adapter in onViewCreated() method which I mention in my answer